# Replace $ref with custom attribute for specific types

Tags: json.net, jsonschema

Is it possible to replace a type's `$ref` attribute with a custom attribute, but only for specific types in the schema? It appears the JSON.NET Schema library is all-or-nothing for custom schema handling.

The [sample code](https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema/help/html/CreateCustomProvider.htm) is pretty simplistic, but as far as I can tell, once you add a type to `GenerationProviders`, the library doesn't provide automatic schema generation for types deeper into the class hierarchy. (I can't share code, this is a locked-down banking system with no Internet access.)

We are using schema files generated from a whole hierarchy of .NET C# classes to generate corresponding Java classes with Java's Jackson library. A few of the class properties are complex types which can't be represented or generated from the schema, and should instead reference existing class definitions, while the rest of the class properties (the majority of them) should use normal `$ref` attributes.

So by default, the C# class hierarchy might generate something like this:

```json
"AccountType": {
    "$ref": "#/definitions/AccountTypeCode"
    },
```

whereas Jackson needs this:

```json
"AccountType": {
    "existingJavaType": "com.foo.bar.pojo.AccountTypeCode"
    },
```

Right now we're sort of post-processing the schema with hokey string replacements, but this feels like something that is probably a supported use-case.

Comment: You don't provide a [mcve], but is this what you're looking for?  https://dotnetfiddle.net/NRjDkp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate such a schema using a [custom `JSchemaGenerationProvider`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema/help/html/CreateCustomProvider.htm), though there is an extra complication involved in completely suppressing the presence of internal `"$ref"` properties.

Consider the following simplified example:

```
public class Account
{
    public AccountTypeCode AccountType { get; set; }
    public SomeOtherData SomeOtherData { get; set; }
}

public class AccountTypeCode { }

public class SomeOtherData { }
```

You would like to generate a schema for this data model in which `AccountTypeCode` uses a specific existingJavaType, and everything else is unchanged, like so:

```
{
  "definitions": {
    "SomeOtherData": {
      "type": [
        "object",
        "null"
      ]
    }
  },
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "AccountType": {
      "existingJavaType": "com.foo.bar.pojo.AccountTypeCode"
    },
    "SomeOtherData": {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/SomeOtherData"
    }
  }
}
```

As a first attempt at injecting an existingJavaType schema for any subset of POCO types, subclass `JSchemaGenerationProvider` and override [`GetSchema()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Schema_Generation_JSchemaGenerationProvider_GetSchema.htm) and [`CanGenerateSchema()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Schema_Generation_JSchemaGenerationProvider_CanGenerateSchema.htm) as follows:

```
class ExistingJavaTypeSchemaProvider : JSchemaGenerationProvider
{
    readonly Dictionary<Type, string> existingJavaTypes;

    public ExistingJavaTypeSchemaProvider(Dictionary<Type, string> existingJavaTypes) 
        => this.existingJavaTypes = existingJavaTypes ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(existingJavaTypes));

    public override JSchema GetSchema(JSchemaTypeGenerationContext context)
        => existingJavaTypes.TryGetValue(context.ObjectType, out var existingJavaType) ? JSchema.Parse(new JObject(new JProperty("existingJavaType", existingJavaType)).ToString()) : null;

    public override bool CanGenerateSchema(JSchemaTypeGenerationContext context) 
        => existingJavaTypes.ContainsKey(context.ObjectType);
}
```

(By overriding `CanGenerateSchema()` you can fall back to default schema generation for all but the specified types.  This is not shown in the [docs](https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema/help/html/CreateCustomProvider.htm) and may have lead you into thinking Json.NET Schema does not support mixing of default and custom schemas.)

Now generate a schema as follows, injecting the required existingJavaType value for `AccountTypeCode`:

```
var generator =  new JSchemaGenerator
{
    GenerationProviders = { new ExistingJavaTypeSchemaProvider(new Dictionary<Type, string>
                                                               {{ typeof(AccountTypeCode), "com.foo.bar.pojo.AccountTypeCode" }}
                                                              ) },
};
generator.DefaultRequired = Required.Default;
var schema = generator.Generate(typeof(Account));
```

This results in the following schema (demo fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/URdA3E)):

```
{
  "definitions": {
    "AccountTypeCode": {
      "existingJavaType": "com.foo.bar.pojo.AccountTypeCode"
    },
    "SomeOtherData": {
      "type": [
        "object",
        "null"
      ]
    }
  },
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "AccountType": {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/AccountTypeCode"
    },
    "SomeOtherData": {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/SomeOtherData"
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, we're halfway there.  The existingJavaType has been inserted as required, however `AccountTypeCode` has been extracted as a local definition rather than inlined.  While it is possible to inline **all** definitions by setting [`JSchemaGenerator.SchemaLocationHandling`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Schema_Generation_JSchemaGenerator_SchemaLocationHandling.htm) to [`SchemaLocationHandling.Inline`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Schema_Generation_SchemaLocationHandling.htm), there does not appear to be a way to force a particular type to be inlined.  However, a quick perusal of the [reference source](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json.Schema/blob/e648e4b2e9eb87bad7c2494c4b7b060ac13a3db4/Src/Newtonsoft.Json.Schema/Generation/JSchemaGeneratorInternal.cs#L320) shows that references are only generated for object, array and dictionary contracts.  Thus creating a [custom contract resolver](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/contractresolver.htm#CustomIContractResolverExamples) that returns some other contract for `AccountTypeCode`, say [`JsonStringContract`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonStringContract.htm), would force inlining.  Or course this would also modify the schema generated -- but you're already manually generating the schema anyway, thus doing so is harmless.

**Putting the two pieces together**, the following factory can manufacture a schema generator for types that contain `AccountTypeCode`:

```
public static class ExistingJavaTypeJSchemaGeneratorFactory
{
    class ExistingJavaTypeSchemaProvider : JSchemaGenerationProvider
    {
        readonly Dictionary<Type, string> existingJavaTypes;
        
        public ExistingJavaTypeSchemaProvider(Dictionary<Type, string> existingJavaTypes) 
            => this.existingJavaTypes = existingJavaTypes ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(existingJavaTypes));
        
        public override JSchema GetSchema(JSchemaTypeGenerationContext context)
            => existingJavaTypes.TryGetValue(context.ObjectType, out var existingJavaType) ? JSchema.Parse(new JObject(new JProperty("existingJavaType", existingJavaType)).ToString()) : null;

        public override bool CanGenerateSchema(JSchemaTypeGenerationContext context) 
            => existingJavaTypes.ContainsKey(context.ObjectType);
    }

    class ExistingJavaTypeContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
    {
        readonly Dictionary<Type, string> existingJavaTypes;
        
        public ExistingJavaTypeContractResolver(Dictionary<Type, string> existingJavaTypes) 
            => this.existingJavaTypes = existingJavaTypes ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(existingJavaTypes));

        protected override JsonContract CreateContract(Type objectType) 
            => existingJavaTypes.ContainsKey(objectType) ? new JsonStringContract(objectType) : base.CreateContract(objectType);
    }
    
    public static JSchemaGenerator CreateJSchemaGenerator(Dictionary<Type, string> existingJavaTypes)
        => new JSchemaGenerator
           {
               GenerationProviders = { new ExistingJavaTypeSchemaProvider(existingJavaTypes) },
               ContractResolver = new ExistingJavaTypeContractResolver(existingJavaTypes),
           };
}
```

And then use it as follows:

```
var generator = ExistingJavaTypeJSchemaGeneratorFactory.CreateJSchemaGenerator(
    new Dictionary<Type, string>
    {
        {typeof(AccountTypeCode), "com.foo.bar.pojo.AccountTypeCode"}
    });
generator.DefaultRequired = Required.Default;
var schema = generator.Generate(typeof(Account));
```

Demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/P6w2AY).